# iptable log on ssh

Tags: centos, iptables

I have the following iptables rules that are working and I can see the log in `/var/log/messages`

```
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 1/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Just-a-LOG: " --log-level 4
```

But the following (used for logging when someone tries to connect with SSH) does not work:

```
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 19600 -m state --state NEW -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -j LOG --log-prefix "Just-a-LOG: " --log-level 4
```

I also started the ip6tables as following:

```
systemctl enable ip6tables
systemctl start ip6tables
```

And added the following rules as well:

```
ip6tables -N LOGGING
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 19600 -m state --state NEW -j LOGGING
ip6tables -A LOGGING -j LOG --log-prefix "Just-a-LOG: " --log-level 4
```

But still not working, what is the problem?

Also here is my `iptables-save` output:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Sep 11 17:43:55 2017
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1025:82269]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1025:694246]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 11 17:43:55 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Sep 11 17:43:55 2017
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [1002:81285]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1025:694246]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 11 17:43:55 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Sep 11 17:43:55 2017
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1025:82269]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1025:82269]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1025:694246]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1025:694246]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
-A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
-A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
-A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
-A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eth0 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eth2 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eth1 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 11 17:43:55 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Sep 11 17:43:55 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [26:1140]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:156]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:213]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [3:213]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:POST_public - [0:0]
:POST_public_allow - [0:0]
:POST_public_deny - [0:0]
:POST_public_log - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -o eth0 -g POST_public
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -o eth2 -g POST_public
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -o eth1 -g POST_public
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -g POST_public
-A POST_public -j POST_public_log
-A POST_public -j POST_public_deny
-A POST_public -j POST_public_allow
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eth0 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eth2 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eth1 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 11 17:43:55 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Sep 11 17:43:55 2017
*filter
:INPUT DROP [23:984]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1025:694246]
:LOGGING - [0:0]
:SSH - [0:0]
:blacklist - [0:0]
:ssh - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 19502 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 19501 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 19600 -m state --state NEW -j LOGGING
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LOGGING -j ACCEPT
-A LOGGING -j LOG --log-prefix "Just-a-LOG: "
-A blacklist -m recent --set --name blacklist --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 11 17:43:55 2017
```

Comment: Have configured ssh to listen on port 19600? Do you have other rules?

Comment: @sebasth yes . Also I think no other rule can affect this one cause I already can connect with SSH through that port.

Comment: Do you run dual stack ipv4/ipv6 and are you connecting using ipv4? With dual stack you need to have similar rules for ip6tables as well.

Comment: @sebasth I edited my question, could you please check again?

Comment: Reply to your earlier comment about other rules: If a rule with  `-j ACCEPT` is matched, the packet is accepted and no further rules are evaluated. If you do have other rules, test with `iptables -I INPUT ... -j LOGGING` (`-I` to insert instead of `-A` to append) to get the logging rules evaluated before other rules (or add the other rules you have to your question).

Comment: @sebasth I tried to remove anything that is overwriting my rules but still not working, is it possible that this like is the problem -> `:INPUT ACCEPT [1002:81285]` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65413/discussion-between-soosh-and-sebasth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the order of `-j LOG` and `-j ACCEPT` rules in your `LOGGING` chain.

Rules are evaluated until a filtering decision is made; or the end of chain is reached, in which case default policy is applied. After matching rule with `-j ACCEPT/REJECT/DROP` no further rules are evaluated.